# Why do I keep getting an "expected expression error" in my While Loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops, while-loop, syntax-error

So I am trying to put a code together for my homework assignment and for some reason I keep getting an expected expression error in the condition of my while loop where I am putting the <= end_money part. The error shows up on the <= . This is the only place in my code where I am getting this error. If someone could pleaseeee help me, I would greatly appreciate it. I've been stuck for so long. Here is the snippet:
Edit: Also there is an ending brace for the while loop, i just forgot to paste it here.

```
int player_total = 0;
int dealer_total = 0;
int player_bet;
int card_value = 0;
const int end_money = 1000;
const int starting_money = 100;
string card;
string response;



while (player_bet >= 0 && <= end_money)
{

    cout << "You have $100. Enter bet: ";
    cin >> player_bet;

    if (player_bet <= starting_money) {
        return true;

    }

    else if (player_bet > starting_money) {
        cout << "You only have $100 to bet. Enter bet: ";
    }
```

Comment: `&& <= end_money`? What are you comparing with `end_money`?

Answer (score 6):

Because that is not a valid expression.

Change this:

```
while (player_bet >= 0 && <= end_money)
```

To:

```
while (player_bet >= 0 && player_bet <= end_money)
```

**Translation:**
    *while player-bet is 0 or bigger, and also while player-bet is end-money or smaller.*

---

Your original expression is roughly:

*while player_bet is zero or bigger and also while **(something unknown and not specified)** is less than or equal to end-money.*